# how to change the javascript code below so my div style toggle starts from display none to display grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi I have a list of project website in my website and by clicking view projects button,
my websites which already are on display will hide and then show by clicking again. I need to start from not viewing the websites and then clicking the button to show and clicking to remove so I need to reverse what I have currently

```js
 const btn = document.getElementById('mybtn');
  const images = document.getElementById('images');



btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  
  if (images.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    images.classList.remove('hidden');
    setTimeout(function () {
      images.classList.remove('transform');
    }, 20);
  } else {
    images.classList.add('transform');    
    images.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
      images.classList.add('hidden');
    }, {
      capture: false,
      once: true,
      passive: false
    });
  }
  
}, false);
```

```css
#mybtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(143, 134, 134, 0.589);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mybtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(245, 38, 38);
}
.view-projects {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.project-images {
  justify-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in ;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.transform {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.image a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(150, 144, 144, 0.233);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.image a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(123, 126, 129, 0.116);

}
```

```html
<div class="view-projects">
       <button id="mybtn">View Projects</button>
</div>

<div id="images" class="project-images">

<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/color-flipper.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/counter.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/movies.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/quotes.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/secrets.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/todo.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `hidden` class to your `<div id="images" class="project-images">`  code. This would resolve your problem.

Comment: thank you that solved my problem but another emerged, the first time i load my site the content is hidden, then i click my button and the content shows up but without transition. i click again and content hides with transition and if i click it shows with transition but the first time upon loading website transition is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Add class `hidden` to your `images` element.

```js
 const btn = document.getElementById('mybtn');
  const images = document.getElementById('images');



btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  
  if (images.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    images.classList.remove('hidden');
    setTimeout(function () {
      images.classList.remove('transform');
    }, 20);
  } else {
    images.classList.add('transform');    
    images.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
      images.classList.add('hidden');
    }, {
      capture: false,
      once: true,
      passive: false
    });
  }
  
}, false);
```

```css
#mybtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(143, 134, 134, 0.589);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mybtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(245, 38, 38);
}
.view-projects {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.project-images {
  justify-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in ;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.transform {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
.image a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(150, 144, 144, 0.233);
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.image a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(123, 126, 129, 0.116);

}
```

```html
<div class="view-projects">
       <button id="mybtn">View Projects</button>
</div>

<div id="images" class="project-images hidden">

<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/color-flipper.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/counter.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/movies.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/quotes.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/secrets.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
       <img src="./images/projects/todo.PNG" alt="">
       <a href="">View Website</a>
       <a href="">View Source</a>
</div>
       
</div>
```